# Static assert to check static const class data members?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, static-assert

I have several classes with "static const" data members.
I would like to know how to check their values at compile time with static_assert. 
Can I put static_assert directly in the class body ?
(Putting my static_assert in every constructor is not very practical.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `static_assert()` can be placed everywhere a declaration can, too. That includes the body of a class:

```
class C {
public:
    enum E {
      A, B, C,
      NumEes
    };
    constexpr Foo foos[] = { {...}, {...}, {...} };
    static_assert( NumEes == sizeof foos / sizeof *foos, "size mismatch" );

    // ...
};
```